# Why asp-for input tag helper always use form data instead of the viewmodel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My goal is, when a form is submitted, to be able to display the form again, but with a modified model, where I replace some values.

Take this simplified code for example:

```cs
public class IndexController : Controller
{
  [HttpGet("")]
  public IActionResult Index()
  {
    return View(new IndexViewModel() { Origin = "GET" });
  }

  [HttpPost("")]
  public IActionResult Index(IndexViewModel viewModel)
  {
    viewModel.Origin = "POST";
    viewModel.Name = "Fixed Name"; // I want to force this value
    return View(viewModel);
  }
}

public class IndexViewModel
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public string Origin { get; set; }
}
```

The following view:

```html
@model IndexViewModel

<html>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        Name : <input asp-for="Name" /><br />
        Origin : @Model.Origin
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I submit the form, the method goes through the POST method, but the view HTML only use the original form values.

The value "Fixed Name" is ignored and never used when rendering the view.

I suppose the `asp-for` tag helper always give higher priority to `FormCollection` values. Is there a way to force the use of the Model value ?

Comment: I could render the viewmodel value successfully.Why did your Controller extends ControllerBase?There is no View in this context,I get error in this line:`return View(XXX);`.How did you return View?Actually,it exists in Controller,so you need to change to:`public class IndexController : Controller`

Comment: @Rena you are right, the `ControllerBase` was a remaining from my original code base. I removed it.

Comment: As a workaround, I have explicitly set the value `<input asp-for="Name" value="@Model.Name" />`. The tag helper will never overwrite value when set.

Answer (score 0):

I cant answer why this happens, possibly someone more knowledgable can, but I've had to use the [Post-Redirect-Get](https://andrewlock.net/post-redirect-get-using-tempdata-in-asp-net-core/) pattern:

```
  [HttpPost("")]
  public IActionResult Index(IndexViewModel viewModel)
  {
    viewModel.Origin = "POST";
    // persist model or use TempData
    return RedirectToAction("AfterPost");   
  }

  public IActionResult AfterPost()
  {
    // get model or retrieve from TempData
    viewModel.Name = "Fixed Name"; // I want to force this value
    return View(viewModel);
  }
```

Comment: You are right, it's also the pattern I prefer to use. But in this case, I need to display back the form (it is considered invalid by some process), but change some values that were submitted by the user. TempData could do the trick... but will start to require some session state that I would prefer to not depend on.

Comment: I'm not sure if `Core` has "Value Providers", but in theory you could write a custom value provider that binds your model value instead of the posted value.